# Can mprotect() be used to change the permissions of .rodata?

Tags: linux, kernel

The `.rodata` segment in ELF files contains data that is not meant to be changed. By default, all pages from this segment are read-only, and any attempt at modification will trigger a general protection fault. The Linux syscall `mprotect()` is capable of modifying the access permissions on a per-page basis. I am wondering if the read-only nature of `.rodata` is enforced by the kernel such that syscalls like that cannot change its access permissions, or if the kernel simply sets the default permissions for the page. If the former is true, then the read-only data segment can be relied upon to prevent even a compromised program from modifying it at runtime.

**Does the Linux kernel enforce the read-only nature of `.rodata`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Sections do not exist in the context of a running process, only segments.
- `mprotect` can be used to change the permissions of the pages the `text` segment is mapped to. Here is a tutorial on how to accomplish this: [Writing a Self-Mutating x86_64 C Program](https://shanetully.com/2013/12/writing-a-self-mutating-x86_64-c-program/)
- from the notes on the [`mprotect` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect):

  > On Linux it is always permissible to call mprotect() on any address in a process's address space (except for the kernel vsyscall area). **In particular it can be used to change existing code mappings to be writable**.

---

Section information is stored in the section header table. The section header table is an array of section headers. The section header table is not mapped to any segment, and not parsed by the program loader. The loader uses segment information only when mapping a program into virtual memory.

Segments - not sections - have permissions, and these are stored in the   segment's program header in the `p_flags` field. Program headers reside in the binary's program header table.

All of this is documented in chapters 4 and 5 in the [System V ABI (generic)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi41.pdf).

In the output below, we can see the permissions associated with each segment under the `flags` column:

```
$ readelf -l /bin/ls

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x404890
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000019d44 0x0000000000019d44  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000019df0 0x0000000000619df0 0x0000000000619df0
                 0x0000000000000804 0x0000000000001570  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000019e08 0x0000000000619e08 0x0000000000619e08
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000000000001701c 0x000000000041701c 0x000000000041701c
                 0x000000000000072c 0x000000000000072c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000019df0 0x0000000000619df0 0x0000000000619df0
                 0x0000000000000210 0x0000000000000210  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

> The `.rodata` section in ELF files contains parts of the text segment that are not meant to be changed.

This is false. The entire `text` segment is Read/Execute.

> By default, all pages from this section are read-only, and any attempt at modification will trigger a general protection fault.

This is false. Segments, not sections,  are mapped to pages (hence the `Align` values) and have permissions (hence the `Flags` values).

More info can be found here:

- http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/
- http://nairobi-embedded.org/040_elf_sec_seg_vma_mappings.html#section-segment-vma-mappings

Comment: Great explanation! Do you know if it would be possible, in theory, for the kernel to enforce this read-only behavior? If so, then it would likely not be too difficult to safely whitelist strings using seccomp-bpf by ensuring the strings are in `.rodata` (since seccomp can only whitelist register contents, e.g. pointers, not the strings themselves).

Comment: I can think of it being doable with a new `mprotect()` flag (`PROT_READ|PROT_LOCK` or so) which would permanently set the pages specified read-only, and this could be called by `ld.so` to make `.rodata` permanently, for the read-only, for the runtime of the process. However I think it would be easier and more elegant if the kernel itself were to be aware of which pages are in `.rodata` (which is what I'm currently looking into reading your links).

Comment: @forest The following articles appear to be relevant: 1)  https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/PaX_Quickstart#Judicious_enforcement_of_non-executable_memory 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX#Enforced_non-executable_pages 3) https://pax.grsecurity.net/docs/mprotect.txt 4) https://lwn.net/Articles/643797/

Comment: Funny, I was just reading through those. I'm on a system with PaX, looked at the `/proc/self/maps`, and realized that the whole relevant segment was executable, so PaX MPROTECT would prevent it from being marked writable again. `mprotect(0x4d31a09000, 1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)` :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html):

> On  Linux it is always permissible to call mprotect() on any address in
>   a process's address space (except for the kernel  vsyscall  area).   In
>   particular  it  can  be  used  to  change  existing code mappings to be
>   writable.

Here's a sample program to demonstrate.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

const unsigned char rodata[3*PAGE_SIZE] = {1,2,3};

int main(void)
{
    printf("rodata = %p\n", rodata);
    uintptr_t page_base = ((uintptr_t)rodata / PAGE_SIZE + 1) * PAGE_SIZE;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)rodata + PAGE_SIZE;
    //*p = '!'; // this would cause a segfault
    puts("Before mprotect:");
    system("cat /proc/$PPID/maps");
    if (mprotect((void*)page_base, 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) < 0) {
        perror("mprotect");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("After mprotect:");
    system("cat /proc/$PPID/maps");
    *p = '!';
    return 0;
}
```

Of course any data that you write to the page will remain in memory. Linux sees that the process is writing to a page that's currently mapped read-only and makes a copy. At the time of the write, the kernel doesn't distinguish this from copy-on-write after a process has forked. You can observe this by forking, writing in one process and reading in the other: the other process won't see the write since it's a write to the writing process's memory, not to the reading process's memory.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

const unsigned char rodata[3*PAGE_SIZE] = {0};

void writer(char *p)
{
    if (mprotect(p, 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) < 0) {
        perror("mprotect");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("After mprotect:");
    system("cat /proc/$PPID/maps");
    *p = 1;
    printf("wrote %d\n", *p);
}

void reader(char *p)
{
    printf("read %d\n", *p);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("rodata = %p\n", rodata);
    uintptr_t page_base = (((uintptr_t)rodata / PAGE_SIZE + 1) * PAGE_SIZE);
    volatile char *p = (volatile char *)page_base;
    //*p = '!'; // this would cause a segfault
    puts("Before mprotect:");
    system("cat /proc/$PPID/maps");
    if (fork() == 0) {
        writer(p);
    } else {
        sleep(1);
        reader(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect there are hardening patches that prevent a process from changing its own memory mappings, but I don't have one to offer.